# How do I create a trigger with the below problem statement?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger named `transaction_type_af_insert` that is triggered whenever a new record is inserted into `ransaction_type` table. This trigger will insert the new type and action into the table `transaction_type_log_history` after the insertion of transaction type details. The action name in the affected log table `transaction_type_log_history` is 'After_Insert_transaction_type'.

But facing below error:

```
Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
insert into transaction_type(id,type)values(22,'Credit Card')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04098: trigger 'P12097.TRANSACTION_TYPE_AF_INSERT' is invalid and failed
re-validation
```

Please help me resolve the issue

```
CREATE TRIGGER transaction_type_af_insert
AFTER INSERT 
ON transaction_type FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
type varchar(30)
action varchar(30)
BEGIN
UPDATE transaction_type_log_history
SET action = 'After_Insert_transaction_type'
    WHERE transaction_type.id = transaction_type_log_history.id;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query the `user_errors` view to see what is actually wrong; some clients let you `show errors` as a shortcut after you create the object (SQL Developer, SQLcl, SQL*Plus..) and see the 'Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors' message. With your current code that will say something like:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:
>
> ; is default authid as force under accessible

`type` is [a reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-reserved-words-keywords.html) so you can't use that for a local variable name - it's expecting you to be declaring a record type. Changing the name of that variable reveals the next error:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ACTION" when expecting one of the following:
>
> := ; not null default character

which is because you don't have semicolons after your declarations.

Fixing that still gets 'ORA-00904: "TRANSACTION_TYPE"."ID": invalid identifier' because your update statement doesn't include the `transaction_type` table. You can use [correlation names](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-4CF74E99-8859-4AB1-96E7-07898A2ABB9E) to refer to data in the original table row statement the trigger fired against, using `:new` by default; so this now compiles:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER transaction_type_af_insert
AFTER INSERT ON transaction_type
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  l_type varchar2(30);
  l_action varchar2(30);
BEGIN
  UPDATE transaction_type_log_history
  SET action = 'After_Insert_transaction_type'
  WHERE transaction_type_log_history.id = :new.id;
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bec9702da28a125549e7b8702821edb6)

You aren't actually using either of the the two locally declared variables so you can remove those and the `declare` keyword.

You also seem to be trying to update the history table instead of inserting a new row there, which the problem statement seems to suggest you should be doing.